# How To Prevent Download From Opening on Mobile Javascript/Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mobile, download, createobjecturl

I have a Vue application that allows for a user to download a .pdf file. Currently, if a user clicks the file download button on a mobile device, it downloads and automatically opens. I'm wanting to try and have this download occur in the "background" only and not have it take over their screen when it's finished downloading. How can I prevent this behavior? The code for the button:

```
export const fileDownload = (file, content) => {
  var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "application/pdf" });
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = file;
  link.click();
  URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
};
```